# Java SE programming with Bluetooth client

Tags: java, bluetooth

I try to develop code in Java SE, almost I have been a completed my code (code is decoding GPS nmea0183 protocol) now facing one problem, my GPS device send me data stream which my code is decode and than display graphically.

But I am not sure to how Bluetooth data would be received through code. Anybody can tell me how can give path Bluetooth data to my code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a library for communicating with the bluetooth network stack in your OS. Take a look at: http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/